How to create a curve on top of app bar when selected
I am creating one mobile appbar. I am trying to create a curve above when user selects it.i created another curve div. but that is separate div. so it hasn't worked out.  I tried but I don't how to implement it. Can anyone help me with that. I need a curve above when the user clicked on the item

Here's the code:
import { AiFillBell } from "react-icons/ai";
import { GoHomeFill } from "react-icons/go";
import { IoMdSettings } from "react-icons/io";
import { FaUser } from "react-icons/fa";
import { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [selectedItem, setSelectedItem] = useState("home");

  const menuItems = [
    {
      name: "notification",
      icon: <AiFillBell style={{ height: "24px", width: "24px" }} />,
    },
    {
      name: "home",
      icon: <GoHomeFill style={{ height: "24px", width: "24px" }} />,
    },
    {
      name: "settings",
      icon: <IoMdSettings style={{ height: "24px", width: "24px" }} />,
    },
    {
      name: "user",
      icon: <FaUser style={{ height: "24px", width: "24px" }} />,
    },
  ];

  return (
    <div style={{ background: "black", height: "100vh", padding: "50px" }}>
      <div
        style={{
          background: "#0a0e18",
          height: "58px",
          borderRadius: "20px",
          display: "flex",
          alignItems: "center",
          justifyContent: "space-between",
          padding: "0px 30px",
          border: "1px solid #2e3239",
        }}
      >
        {menuItems.map((item, index) => (
          <div
            key={index}
            onClick={() => setSelectedItem(item.name)}
            style={{
              opacity: selectedItem === item.name ? 1 : 0.2,
              cursor: "pointer",
              color: "#fff",
            }}
          >
            {item.icon}
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}


I think you'll need to programmatically generate an SVG path that describes a rounded rectangle with a bulge, and then use that as the background for the div. I'd start by sketching one out in your SVG editor of choice, then tweaking the path data for the 5 bulge positions (or if you're fancy, make it entirely procedural).

@AKX, Thanks for the suggestion. I will try that out..

Or play with a shaped pseudo-element - https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/YzoWWPO

@Paulie_D, Thanks..

@Paulie_D I'm afraid it'll be pretty difficult to make that smooth like OP's image, with a border applied too.

You can use this trick


const indicator = document.querySelector('.indicator');
const items = document.querySelectorAll('li');

items.forEach(item => {
    item.addEventListener('click', e => {
        indicator.style.left = `${item.offsetLeft}px`;
        indicator.style.width = `${item.offsetWidth}px`;
        
        // remove active class from all items
        items.forEach(item => {
            item.classList.remove('active');
        });
        
        // add active class to clicked item
        item.classList.add('active');
    });
});
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    display: grid;
    place-items: center;
    height: 100vh;
    background: black;
}

.navigation-bar {
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
    height: 65px;
    background: #0a0e18;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 5px 15px;
    /* use drop-shadow to add border */
    filter: drop-shadow(1px 0 0 #2e3239)
            drop-shadow(-1px 0 0 #2e3239)
            drop-shadow(0 1px 0 #2e3239)
            drop-shadow(0 -1px 0 #2e3239);
}

ul {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    list-style: none;
    height: 100%;
}

li {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    display: grid;
    place-items: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 50%;
    z-index: 2;
    transition: 0.5s;
    color: white;
}


li.active {
    background: red;
}

.indicator {
    position: absolute;
    top: -15px;
    left: 15px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #0a0e18;
    border-radius: 50%;
    transition: 0.5s;
    z-index: 1;
}


.indicator::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: -7px;
    left: -15px;
    width: 22px;
    height: 22px;
    background-color: transparent;
    /* Remove the comment to see how it works well */
    /* background-color: green; */
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-shadow: 7px 17px #0a0e18;
}

.indicator::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: -7px;
    right: -15px;
    width: 22px;
    height: 22px;
    background-color: transparent;
    /* Remove the comment to see how it works well */
    /* background-color: green; */
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-shadow: -7px 17px #0a0e18;
}
<div class="navigation-bar">
    <ul>
      <li class="active">1</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>3</li>
      <li>4</li>
      <li>5</li>
      <div class="indicator"></div>
    </ul>
</div>




Nice – but the right edge of the arc doesn't seem to be smoothed (at least not on my Chrome)?

They adjusted the answer and didn't pay attention to the value of color.
I changed it to the right value.
